# add content on new line in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

i have a script which add content to the file(.properties) but the below script add content after the last character of file but i want to add content on new line. I had tried `n but it create a blank line  and then add content every time my add content command runs

```
$Inputstring =@"
abc
def
ghi
"@

$list = @"
server_name1,server_name2,server_name3
"@
$lists = $list.split(",")
Foreach ($server in $lists) {   
    Add-content "path" $Inputstring
    
    
}
```

Comment: What does `$env:servers` contain exactly?

Comment: `-Path` should be the path to the .properties file and you need to specify the value it should write in there: `foreach ($thing in $listOfThings) { Add-Content -Path 'X:\Path\To\The\.properties' -Value "`r`n$thing" }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen My bad , i have edited the code.

Comment: @Theo sorry , i have edited my code now previous one was a mistake

Comment: @Theo the content is in $inputString and for each is use to loop in servers

Comment: Then.. why the need for a list of servers? Do you want to add the `$InputString` to a file that each server has somewhere? Please try and explain better what you actually want to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

I ***ASSUME*** this question is about how to append a certain string to a file on various servers with an extra newline above it.

In that case you need to construct the (UNC) path to the file for each server and then use `Add-Content` on that file in a loop.

Suppose every server has that file in its local `C:\Temp\TheFile.properties`, then the code could be like this:

```
$Inputstring =@"
abc
def
ghi
"@

# string array of servers. Could also be done with
# $servers = 'server_name1,server_name2,server_name' -split ','
$servers = 'server_name1','server_name2','server_name'

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    # construct the UNC path to the file on each server
    $path = "\\$server\C$\Temp\TheFile.properties"
    Add-content -Path $path -Value "`r`n$Inputstring"
}
```

If my assumption about your intention is wrong, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68437638/edit) and make clear what it is you want to do. Preferably with examples.